# JTextArea change its size when font or text size is changed

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, jcomponent

I'm beginner in Java and I'm trying to make a simple text editor where the font and text size can be changed. It works although it has an issue that it seems that the **text area size is fixed to the font and text size** when something is changed.
**I want the text area size all time be the same**. I was debugging and I realize that **rows and columns of text area never change**.

Image before change font:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/83nzf.png]

Image after change font:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AA2j.png]

***Full code:***

```
public class Run {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        MainFrame main_frame = new MainFrame();
    }
}

public class MainFrame extends JFrame{

    private TextAreaPanel text_area_panel = new TextAreaPanel(60, 20);
    private ComboBoxesPanel combo_boxes_panel = new ComboBoxesPanel(this.text_area_panel);
    
    public MainFrame() {
        this.initUI();
    }
    
    private void initUI() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(combo_boxes_panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(text_area_panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setSize(getToolkit().getScreenSize().width / 2, getToolkit().getScreenSize().height / 2);
        setLocation(getToolkit().getScreenSize().width / 4, getToolkit().getScreenSize().height / 4);
        setTitle("Simple Text Editor");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}

public class TextAreaPanel extends JPanel{
    
    private JTextArea text_area = new JTextArea();
    private JScrollPane scroll_text_area = new JScrollPane(text_area);
    
    public TextAreaPanel(int width, int height) {
        this.addComponets();
        setTextAreaSize(width, height);
    }
    
    private void addComponets() {
        add(scroll_text_area);
    }
    
    public void setTextAreaSize(int width, int height) {
        text_area.setRows(height);
        text_area.setColumns(width);
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        //setTextAreaSize(getWidth() / 15, getHeight() / 20);
    }
    
    public JTextArea getArea() {
        return this.text_area;
        }
}

public class ComboBoxesPanel extends JPanel{
    
    private String[] system_fonts = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getAvailableFontFamilyNames();
    private Object[] sizes = {8,10,12,14,16,20,24,36, 48};
    private JComboBox font_box = new JComboBox(system_fonts);
    private JComboBox size_box = new JComboBox(sizes);
    private TextAreaPanel text_area_panel;
    
    public ComboBoxesPanel(TextAreaPanel text_area_panel) {
        this.text_area_panel = text_area_panel;
        font_box.addActionListener(font_listener);
        size_box.addActionListener(size_listener);
        add(font_box);
        add(size_box);
    }
    
    private ActionListener font_listener = new ActionListener() {
        
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            
            (text_area_panel.getArea()).setFont(new Font((String)font_box.getSelectedItem(),
                    Font.PLAIN, (int)size_box.getSelectedItem()));
        }
    };
    
    private ActionListener size_listener = new ActionListener() {
        
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            (text_area_panel.getArea()).setFont(new Font((String)font_box.getSelectedItem(),
                    Font.PLAIN, (int)size_box.getSelectedItem()));
        }
    };
    
}
```

Anyone knows how to solve this issue? Any idea how to solve this?
Also **all the code in my GitLab repository** if anyone wants to help.
https://gitlab.com/RichardCG/simpletexteditor
Thanks. :)

Comment: [`JTextArea​(int rows, int columns)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#%3Cinit%3E(int,int)) allows the `JTextArea` to automatically calculate the "default" size of the `JTextArea` and it's based, loosely, on the `Font`, so you experience would be expected.  `JTextArea` implements `Scrollable`, which means, if it's really important to you, you could override the [`getPreferredScrollableViewportSize`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#getPreferredScrollableViewportSize()) and specify you own desired scrollable size

Answer (score 1):

First of all I will rant a little about your variable names.

When you create a JTextArea you specify the "rows/columns" of the text area:

1. why do you use "width/height" as the variable names in your class? In Swing "width/height" are used to represent pixel values.
2. why did you change the order of the variables? You specify the "row, column" as the parameters of the text area. Why would you change your parameter order to "width, height". The "width" does NOT correlate to "rows".

It is confusing when the API is not consistent.

> it seems that the text area size is fixed to the font and text size

Correct, all Swing components are responsible for determining their own preferred size. The size is based on the properties of the component. So when you change the font or font size the component will recalculate its preferred size.

This is a good thing as it allows:

1. the layout mangers to work properly
2. the scroll pane to work properly as the scrollbars will appear when needed.

> I want the text area size all time be the same

You can control the size of the scroll pane, which in turn will keep the text area size the size while showing/hiding scrollbars as required.

In the constructor of you class you can add:

```
int scrollBarSize = UIManager.getInt("ScrollBar.width");
Dimension d = text_area.getPreferredSize();
d.width += scrollBarSize;
d.height += scrollBarSize;
scroll_text_area.setPreferredSize(d);
```

This works because the FlowLayout respects the preferred size of any component added to the panel.

**However, this is NOT a good solution. Instead you should design your editor to be more user friendly.**

For any editor I've used the editor component takes up all the available space in the frame. So you may have a tool bar (at the top), or status bar (at the bottom) and the editor takes up the remaining space. This allows the editor size to change as the user resizes the frame.

So typically you would just set the row/columns of the JTextArea when you create the text area and add the text area to a JScrollPane. Then the scroll pane is added to the CENTER of the BorderLayout on the. frame and you then `pack()` the frame BEFORE making the frame visible.

There is no need for the TextAreaPanel class.